# Brace Expansion doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Having simple example:

> echo Front-{A,B,C}-Back

The brace expansion seems not to work. I got just:

> Front-{A,B,C}-Back

instead of:

> Front-A-Back Front-B-Back Front-C-Back

Why doesn't it work?

PS. I'm running on Slackware 14.2 on a bash shell.

Comment: Most likely you aren't running `bash` as you think (possibly `ash`/`dash`)

Comment: Check out if there is `braceexpand` option in the output of `echo $SHELLOPTS`.
If it's missing try `set -B` to switch it on.

Comment: What does `echo $0` return?